# how to join three tables ,add two separate fields from two tables and then finally group by two separate fields from two tables

Tags: mysql

i have three tables admins,table2,table3

admins structure is

```
admins_id  | admin_name | admin_username
1          | ABC        |1234
2          | Cde        |456
```

table2 sturcture is

```
table2mask |table2adminid | table2maskcount
mask1      |1              |30
mask2      |1              |60
```

table3 structure is

```
table3mask |table3adminid | table3maskcount
mask1      |1              |30
mask2      |1              |70
mask3      |2              |10
```

what i want to achieve is

```
username   | mask        |ttlCount
1234       | mask1       | 60
1234       | mask2       | 130
456        | mask3       | 10
```

how should i achieve that

i tried using query given below

```
SELECT admins.`admin_username`, 
(table2.`table2maskcount`+table3.`table3maskcount`) AS ttl_counts from 
admins inner join table2 on table2.`table2adminid` = admins.`admin_id` inner 
join table3 on table3.`table3adminid` = admins.`admin_id` Where 
table2.`table2mask`=table3.`table3mask`
```

but its not giving me the accurate result its not showing count of mask that is only available in one of either tables

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join `admins` to the union of the other 2 tables, `group by admin` and `mask` and aggregate:

```
select a.admin_username username, t.mask, sum(maskcount) ttlcount
from admins a inner join (
  select 
    table2mask mask, 
    table2adminid adminid, 
    table2maskcount maskcount 
  from table2
  union all
  select * from table3
) t on t.adminid = a.admins_id 
group by a.admins_id, a.admin_username, t.mask
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m21u3PKnrJrJQveFLxpogz/1).
Results:

```
| username | mask  | ttlcount |
| -------- | ----- | -------- |
| 1234     | mask1 | 60       |
| 1234     | mask2 | 130      |
| 456      | mask3 | 10       |
```